# c# programming. making sure there is no duplicate

Tags: c#

So basically I have to create a lottery program that is between 1-4. The user guesses 3 numbers and you have to see if they match all three number. My problem is that to get to the grand prize. You have to match your guess with the random number in the correct sequence. For example.

```
if (guess1 == ran1 && guess2 == ran2 && guess3 == ran3)
                Console.WriteLine("$10,000");
```

But also, if you match three number in a incorrect sequence. You still get $1000 dollars. but here is where I run into a problem. I wrote my code for $1000 like this

```
     {if (guess1 == ran1)
                ++matches;
            else
                if (guess1 == ran2)
                    ++matches;
                else
                    if (guess1 == ran3)
                        ++matches;

        }
        {
            if (guess1 == ran1)
                ++matches;
            else
                if (guess1 == ran2)
                    ++matches;
                else
                    if (guess1 == ran3)
                        ++matches;
        }
        {
            if (guess1 == ran1)
                ++matches;
            else
                if (guess1 == ran2)
                    ++matches;
                else
                    if (guess1 == ran3)
                        ++matches;
 if (matches == 3)
                    Console.WriteLine("$1000");
```

So every time you win the grand prize, you win 10,000 dollars AND 1,000 dollars, but this is not what I want.

Is there anyway I can fix it so when the user enters the lottery number in correct sequence they only win 10,000 dollars not both? Please note that this is a basic programming class. Nothing really fancy.

Comment: First check if the user guessed them in the correct order. **ELSE**, check if he guessed them in an incorrect order.

Comment: We have no idea what this code is. but I can say there is definitely a better way than this. "Programming = Algorithm + DataStructure". Here I don't see any use of data structure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if (guess1 == ran1 && guess2 == ran2 && guess3 == ran3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("$10000");
}
else if ((guess1 == ran1 || guess1 == ran2 || guess1 == ran3) && 
         (guess2 == ran1 || guess2 == ran2 || guess2 == ran3) && 
         (guess3 == ran1 || guess3 == ran2 || guess3 == ran3))
{
    Console.WriteLine("$1000");
}
```

This should work. You might also want to check your variable names; it seems you're probably forgetting to increment the numbers at the end of the variable names in your comparisons.

Comment: The question states that winning the grand prize **also** wins the smaller prize.

Comment: No, the question states that his problem is that the code he's using triggers both the $10,000 and the $1,000 prize, but he only wants the grand prize winner to get the $10,000 prize. "The user wins 10,000 dollars AND 1,000 dollars. Is there anyway I can fix it. So when the user enters the lottery number in correct sequence they only win 10,000 dollars **not both**?"

Comment: Wow, I'd read that para of the question twice and read it wrong both times!

Comment: No problem. Make sure you understand my answer so you can apply it to the next challenges you face though. Particularly the [&&](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) and [||](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx) operators.

Comment: This gets some cases but not all. If the random numbers are `{1,2,3}` then you'll correctly pay out if the user guesses `{2,3,1}` or `{3,1,2}` but will fail to pay out if they guess `{1,3,2}` or `{3,2,1}` or `{2,1,3}`.

Answer (score 3):

Is LINQ fancy?

```
bool userGuessedInOrder = guesses.SequenceEqual(correctNumbers);

bool userGuessedInSomeOrder = !guesses.Except(correctNumbers).Any();
```

Comment: Am missing how `Except` takes care of ordering?

Comment: @Sriram It doesn't. That's the objective, isn't it?

Comment: To be honest I don't read this question fully. and probably I won't. My comment is solely based on your variable name `userGuessedInSomeOrder`, I read it means user guessed in expected order. and FWIW I'm not the downvoter. If this is what OP is asking surely my vote is waiting for you.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel There are two prizes: one for guessing the right numbers in the right order, and one for guessing the right numbers but in the wrong order.

Comment: @ClickRick Thanks for clearing, I don't understand what dump downvoted this. This is the best answer I can think of. +1 Rotem

Comment: I would say that Linq is fancy...a lot of professional C# developers shy away from it even now.

Answer (score 0):

As a slightly simpler LINQ-based solution, this illustrates how to encapsulate your numbers in a data structure, and how to encapsulate your algorithm in a function.

```
public static int Payout(IEnumerable<int> randoms, IEnumerable<int> guesses)
{
    if (randoms.SequenceEqual(guesses))
        return 10000;
    IEnumerable<int> sortedRandoms = randoms.OrderBy(a => a);
    IEnumerable<int> sortedGuesses = guesses.OrderBy(a => a);
    if (sortedRandoms.SequenceEqual(sortedGuesses))
        return 1000;
    return 0;
}
```